# How to add elements individually in tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples, addition

How to add elements individually within the tuple?

For example, i need `(2, 4)` from `(0,1)` + `(2,3)`, I've been doing it as such but is there a more pythonic / less verbose way to do the same?

```
>>> x = (0,1)
>>> y = (2,3)
>>> x + y
(0, 1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple(i+j for i,j in zip(x,y))
(2, 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `sum` here:

**Example:**

```
>>> x = (0, 1)
>>> y = (2, 3)
>>> tuple(map(sum, zip(x, y)))
(2, 4)
```

- `zip` lets us combine elements of two iterables or lists in pairs.
- `sum` lets us sum the pairs
- `map` lets us apply the `sum` function per pair.
- *finally* we convert the resulting list (*or iterable in Python 3.x*) back into a `tuple` since that's what you seem to have wanted.

The above example basically ends up being;

```
(0 + 2, 1 + 3)
```

Comment: +1 But this creates a list; to reprocude the exact result OP wants it would have to be `tuple(map(sum, zip(x, y)))`

Answer (score 2):

Your own solution is the correct way to do that in pure python.

If you'd like to avoid the loop, you can vectorize the operation using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
tuple( np.asarray(tup1) + np.asarray(tup2) )
```

You should only convet the data back to a tuple if you really need it as a tuple. Otherwise, leave is as a numpy array, which means you can apply more vectorized operations to it later.

Also, the second conversion to `np.asarray` is optional. The first one would suffice (the other conversions are automatically done by numpy).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a faster way to add individual elements from tuples using numpy:

```
import numpy as np 

x = (0,1)
y = (2,3)

z = np.array(x) + np.array(y)
z = tuple(z)

z
(2, 4)
```